# I apply Scale on hover but when my icon goes back I want the icon speed to slow as compared to hovering

Tags: hover, css-animations, css-transitions, transform, scale

Description:
I have an icon I apply scale property on hover and transition as well in class , but when I hover the icon it scales fast that's prefect for me but when I remove hover I need to slowly go back the icon as compared to when hover .
Thanks for Help in advance

```
.banner-content #msg-icon {
  width: 4%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 6%;
  right: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.banner-content #msg-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Stuff like "Hey ! I have a question for you guys -->" really does not belong into a proper question title (edited.)

Comment: And please show a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Specifying a different transition duration for the normal and the `:hover` state should do the trick.

Comment: I am new on stack !